# system settings -> shortcuts and gestures

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, kde4

Something is stealing my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> shortcuts from eclipse. I checked out the settings panel from the title but could not spot any such bindings over there. So, how do I get to see who is keeping those key combos and how to unbind them ?

LE: I was blind actually; the keyboard shortcuts were just in the place from title under the "KWin" application.

Comment: What is happening when you press those shortcuts? When eclipse window is in focus/not in focus?

Comment: in eclipse: ctrl f7 : nothing; ctrl f8: all desktops are displayed on screen. Out eclipse: same deal.

Comment: In that case nothing is stealing ctrl-f7. It is simply unbound. Can you try binding it from within Eclipse to your preference and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> is showing "virtual desktops" because the special `desktop effects` are enabled. You need to disable the `desktop effects` in order to unbind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. For more information, see [here](http://www.kde.org/announcements/4.0/desktop.php).

Alternatively, you can configure keyboard shortcuts from system settings to remove the said binding.

These bindings can be changed at System Settings > Common Appearance and Behaviour > Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts > KWin. By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is bound to `Toggle Present Windows (Window Class)` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> is bound to `Show Desktop Grid`.

Comment: turning desktop effects off does the trick. Not the solution I was after though. As said, system settings -> shortcuts and gestures deos not show those shortcuts. So how could I unbind them, where from ?

Comment: I do not have access to KDE, so unable to play .. see if this page helps: http://opensuse-guide.org/kde.php

Comment: @kellogs I have an edit pending, but these bindings can be changed at System Settings > Common Appearance and Behaviour > Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts > KWin. `Toggle Present Windows (Window Class)` and `Show Desktop Grid`.